# Does every category have a functor?

Tags: category-theory, abstract-algebra

Is there any one (or more) categories that doesn't have a functor? Functors go between categories, so is there any category that only has an identity functor but no other functor that maps it to another category?

Comment: You can always define the opposite functor into the opposite category. If the category is symmetric then the opposite category can be identified with it in a natural way, but whether or not this makes it the same category depends on what you want.

Comment: @Alex. I don't get it. What is your opposite functor? In general there is no interesting functor (by which I always mean covariant, since contravariant functors are in fact covariant functors in disguise) $C \to C^{op}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every category has at least 2 outgoing functors: the identity functor plus at least another one. 
Actually every category has infinitely many outgoing functors.
You can easily see this by considering the cases of:

- the empty category which goes to every other one (it is the initial category, after all)
- the non empty categories which go trivially or non trivially to every other non empty and/or non terminal category

However the empty category has only one *ingoing* functor. The identity functor. Every other category has more than one ingoing functor

Comment: The empty category always maps to the empty subcategory of codomain category of every functor, right?

Answer (score 6):

A very strong no! For every two categories $C,D$ and an object $d\in ob(D)$ there is a functor $F:C\to D$ mapping every thing in $C$ to $d$ and $id_d$.

Comment: mapping every thing in C to d or to D?

Comment: every object to $d$ and every arrow to $id_d$.

Comment: Of course, if $D$ is empty...

Comment: $D$ can't be empty since it is assumed to contain at least one object $d$.

Comment: Who assumes that? :) For me, sets are discrete categories, including the empty set.

Comment: @Berci I'm just saying that above I said "... $D$ and an object $d\in ob(D)$". Of course I'm not claiming that the empty category does not exist. And as a side note, for me sets are just indiscrete categories.

Answer (score 0):

For every category $C$ there is a functor from $C$ to the category $1$ consisting of exactly one object and one arrow.

So you can map every category $C$ to the category $1$.

Conversely, $1$ can be embedded into any other category.

So every category "has a functor" other than identity functor.

Comment: Of course, for one category this is the identity.

Comment: Your answer is false if taken literally: $1$ does not embed into the empty category, and the category $1$ only has the identity endofunctor.